# AngularJS controls are disables when adding a new record

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning AngularJS and I'm stuck on adding new records. I can open and edit/save existing records, but when I open my edit form to create a new record, all the controls are disabled (I can't type in the textboxes or select a value from a DDL). Here is my code:

Index.cshtml:

```
<script id="ModelList.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><a href="#/SaveModel/0/New">New Rate</a></th>
                <th>Record ID</th>
                <th>Company ID</th>
                <th>Rate</th>               
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr ng-repeat="m in models">
            <td><a href="#/SaveModel/{{m.Rid }}/{{m.StateCode }}" ng-click="select(m)">Edit</a></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="m.Rid"></span></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="m.CompanyId"></span></td>
            <td><span ng-bind="m.Rate"></span></td>         
        </tr>
    </table>
</script>
<script id="ModelSave.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <form name="myForm">
        <div>
            <label>Company ID</label>
            <select name="CompanyId" ng-model="model.CompanyId">    
                <option value="101">101</option>
                <option value="102">102</option>
                <option value="103">103</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Rate</label>
            <input name="WorkCompRt" ng-model="model.Rate"/>
        </div>  
        <div>
            <savebutton  text="Save" action="save()"></savebutton>
            <cancelbutton></cancelbutton>
        </div>
    </form>
</script>
```

.js:

```
    .controller("RecordsListController", function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, State, Services) {

    $scope.select = function (item) { State.broadcast(item); };
    $scope.addNew = function() { $scope.models.splice(0,0,{ }); };

    Services.getRecords().success(function (d) {                
        $scope.models = d;
    });

})
.controller("ViewSaveController", function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, State, Services) {

    $scope.select = function (item) { State.broadcast(item); };
    $scope.addNew = function () { $scope.models.splice(0, 0, {}); };

    Services.getRecord($routeParams.id).success(function (d) {
        $scope.model = d;
    });
})

.factory("Services", function (Api) {

    this.getRecords = function(){
        return Api.get("AppApi/GetRecords");
    };

    this.getRecord = function (rId) {
        return Api.get("AppApi/GetRecordById?rId=" + rId);
    };

    return this;
})
```

So, I'm using the same form for creating and updating records; however, when rId is 0 (new item), the controls on the form are disabled. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a JSFiddle or Plunker. Also, read up on `factory`: you're using it incorrectly here.

Comment: @squid314 - I'm new to AngularJS and have never user JSFiddle or Plunker. Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Usually I start by going to the AngularJS docs pages, find one of the directives, and click on the "Edit in JSFiddle" links right above the example section. Then copy/paste my HTML and JavaScript in where I need.

Comment: Kate, where are the `<savebutton>` and `<cancelbutton>` directives coming from?  It's very possible the code for those directives is what's disabling your inputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Services.getRecord($routeParams.id) function prevents me from entering values in the controls. I created a separate controller for Adding a record that is the same as "ViewSaveController", except that I removed Services.getRecord($routeParams.id) function. It fixed the problem.